# Grabs rows where second column is equal to value

Tags: r, dataframe, modeling

I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
print(animals_in_zoo)

// I only know the name of the first column, the second one is dynamic/based on a previously calculated variable 
animals | dynamic_column_name

// What the data looks like
elefant x
turtle
monkey
giraffe x
swan
tiger   x
```

What I want is to collect the rows in which the second columns' value is equal to "x".

What I want to do is something like:

SELECT * from data where col2 == "x";

After that, I want to grab only the first column and create a string object like "elefant giraffe tiger", but that is the easy part.

Comment: Provide reproducible example: `dput(animals_in_zoo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference that column by its index and use that to get the animals you want:

```r
df1 <- structure(list(animal = c("elefant", "turtle", "monkey", "giraffe", 
                                 "swan", "tiger"), dynamic_column = c("x", NA, NA, "x", NA, "x"
                                 )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

df1[, 1][df1[, 2] == "x" & !is.na(df1[, 2])]
#> [1] "elefant" "giraffe" "tiger"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `filter` with `grepl` which searches for a pattern 'x' in the string:

```
# the data frame

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
'my_col
"elefant x"
turtle
monkey
"giraffe x"
swan
"tiger   x"'
)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(grepl('x', my_col))
```

```
   my_col
1 elefant x
2 giraffe x
3 tiger   x
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[`: the first argument refers to the rows. You want the rows where the second column is `"x"`. The second argument is the column you need in the end, and you want the column named `"animals"`:

```r
dat[dat[2] == "x", "animals"]
#[1] "elefant" "giraffe" "tiger"
```

data

```r
dat <- structure(list(animals = c("elefant", "turtle", "monkey", "giraffe", 
"swan", "tiger"), V2 = c("x", "", "", "x", "", "x")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

#   animals V2
# 1 elefant  x
# 2  turtle   
# 3  monkey   
# 4 giraffe  x
# 5    swan   
# 6   tiger  x
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a dataframe?

If so, something like `df[df$col2 == 'x',]` should work.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't seem to work

Comment: I guess the issue then is how your original file is formatted (if you have a file) and how you are loading the data into r.

Answer (score 0):

With `base` functions, you can do it like this:

```
# Option 1
your_dataframe[your_dataframe$col2 == "x", ]

# Option 2
your_dataframe[your_dataframe[,2] == "x", ]
```

With `dplyr` functions, you can do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)

your_dataframe %>% 
  filter(col2 == "x")
```